# Facebook Login/Signup - Android SDK - Throwing Graphmethod Exception Error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

When using `Facebook login` for users to sign up through `Android SDK` we are getting the following error.

We are **ONLY** requesting `public_profile` and `email`, which are both defaults. However on my account, there is a user_friends which is error ed but we removed it, as we aren't even requesting users_friends from the Android app. It does show as removed by admin under our permissions, but still, I have the option to remove it.

`Error`:

`{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.`

I have this method in a Kotlin Object.

Does anyone have any ideas or help here?

```
  fun signUpByFacebook(activity: Activity, callbackManager: CallbackManager) {

      LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, listOf("public_profile", "email"))
      LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

          override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
              Log.e("Success", loginResult.accessToken.userId)
          }

          override fun onCancel() {
              Log.e("onCancel", "onCancel")
          }

          override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
              Log.e("onError", "onError")
          }
  })
```